# import file with tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

I´m newer in python, I have a problem to import a file in python. My goal is read the file below and then to create a out string below.

```
File:
((781, 572, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8), (1205, 528, 13, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 5), (97, 528, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8), (146, 1257, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8), (1244, 528, 13, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 5), (291, 1257, 12, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 6), (781, 1257, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8)))

Output string:
select * from table where field1=781 and field2=572
select * from table where field1=1205 and field2=528
select * from table where field1=97 and field2=528
.
.
.
```

I´m not sure how can I do this. I tried some code but without sucess.

```
result = []
with open(r"c:\temp\fp\fp.txt", "rb") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        tmp = list(line)
        try:
            result.append(tmp[0], [1])
            #result.append((eval(tmp[0]), eval(tmp[1])))
        except:
             print("a")
print(result)
```

This convert is it posible?

Comment: How is `(781, 572, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8)` converted into `select * from table where field1=781 and field2=572`?

Comment: The "file" is exported from another code in python and the layout is ( (781,572,10, ...), (...) ) the idea is to import the file (could be in a list) and then to create a simple string "Select * from table1 where field1=781 (first value in the tuple) and field2=572 (second value in the tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to stick the first two values of each tuple within the tuple into a string, presumably one that's used as a database query? You can do something like this:

```
yourData = ((781, 572, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8), (1205, 528, 13, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 5))
queryList = []

for t in yourData:
    queryList.append("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1={0} and field2={1};".format(t[0], t[1]))
```

Then, `queryList[0]` contains:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=781 and field2=572;"
```

And `queryList[1]` would contain:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=1205 and field2=528;"
```

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) is some information on the `.format()` method that is used in the above examples.

> EDIT: If your data is in a file, stored in this format `(yourFile.txt)`:

```
(781, 572, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8)
(1205, 528, 13, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 5)
```

Then, you can use the `eval` method to turn the `str` object returned by `readlines()` into a `tuple` and then iterate over that in the above manner. For example:

```
with open("yourFile.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        queryList.append("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1={0} and field2={1};".format(eval(line)[0], eval(line)[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really grateful for your help.

I tested your code and apparently this is very close to the goal, I'll try to make some changes, now I have:

```
["SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=(781, 572, 10, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 8) and field2=(1205, 528, 13, ['2018-11-20-50-56'], 5);"]
```

I´ll try to get the first value (781)

Comment: The code that I posted will give you what you asked for. With the `queryList` you just have to iterate over it to get each individual string.

Comment: Make note of the square brackets `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped you then please accept and upvote it - this will help to help others in the future with a similar issue :)